# Here-API: PDE request returning POIs outside of GeoboundingBox

Tags: java, android, here-api

I am creating an Android-App using the Here SDK and a Here API. In my app I send a request to the PDE (Platform Data Extension) to get POIs of different layers. The request is created with a GeoboundingBox based on my current location as center and with a width  and height each of 20 km.

But apparently the request returns a response, which contains POIs outside of the defined GeoboundingBox.

How does this work? Did I request it wrong? Below is the code:

```java
Set<String> layers = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("POI_SMALLER", "POI_SMALL", "POI_BIG"));
GeoBoundingBox box = new GeoBoundingBox(new GeoCoordinate(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude()), 20000, 20000);
final PlatformDataRequest req = PlatformDataRequest.createBoundingBoxRequest(layers, box);
req.execute((platformDataResult, error) -> {
     //show markers on map
});
```

I marked the POI (filtered by some categories) in my map as blue points, my current location is marked in green. The Top-Left-Coordinate and the Bottom-Right-Coordinate of the GeoboundingBox are marked in yellow (surrounded by red).

I expected the blue markers (found POIs) to be inside the range marked by the yellow markers (Coordinates of the GeoboundingBox), but some of them are outside of it.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide us the coordinate you were using in this example?

Comment: In this case I had a Location with Lat around 52.065 and Lon around 8.715
But this also occured for every other location and also when I created the GeoBoundingBox using two coordinates for the top-left and the bottom-right corners.

Answer (score 0):

We have [here](https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/cle2_pde_search) a demo page where you also can test the behavior of the PDE.

I tried this bounding box: 52.245 ,8.715, 52.065, 8.894  but there are all POIs inside the requested rectangle:

[image]

Can you debug the exact coordinates which are sent out to the PDE in your application and compare it with the yellow ones?